# MySQL MANY to ONE JOIN. How to find both worst (lowest) result and latest result?

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions

**THE DATA**

So, lets say I have a application where I'm testing cars for Speed, Performance, Safety, etc.
I have a set of data in the following format:

```
CAR TABLE
ID  CAR_NAME
1   Ford Focus 2006   
2   Toyota Corolla 2014
5   Tesla Model S 2016

TEST TABLE
ID  TEST_NAME
1   acceleration
2   topSpeed
3   zeroToSixty
4   smoothRide
5   seating
6   ergonomics
7   handling
8   breaking
9   audio

TEST_CATEGORY TABLE
ID  CATEGORY_NAME
1   Speed
2   Performance
3   Comfort
4   Safety

TEST_PLAN TABLE
ID  CAR_ID  CATEGORY_ID TEST_ID 
1   1       1           1       
2   1       1           2       
3   1       1           3       
4   1       2           1       
5   1       2           3       
6   1       2           8       
7   1       2           7       
8   1       4           8       
9   1       4           5       
11  5       1           1       
12  5       1           2       
13  5       1           3       
14  5       1           7       
15  5       2           1       
16  5       2           7       
17  5       2           4       
18  5       3           4       
19  5       3           5       

TEST_INSTANCE TABLE
ID  CAR_ID  TEST_ID CATEGORY_ID GRADE  TEST_DATE
1   1       1       1           C       2015-03-14
2   1       1       1           C       2015-03-17
3   1       1       2           D       2015-03-15
4   1       1       2           C       2015-03-16
5   1       1       2           B       2015-03-17
6   1       3       1           B       2015-03-14
7   1       3       1           C       2015-03-16
8   1       8       2           C       2015-03-13   
9   5       1       1           B       2015-03-15
10  5       1       1           B       2015-03-17
11  5       1       2           A       2015-03-19
12  5       1       2           A       2015-03-12
13  5       7       2           B       2015-03-14
14  5       7       2           B       2015-03-16
15  5       7       2           A       2015-03-18
16  5       7       2           B       2015-03-15
17  5       9       5           A       2015-03-14 --note that this test is not part of the test plan
```

So there's 5 tables, but only the last two (TEST_PLAN, TEST_INSTANCE) are important.  The rest are just JOIN dependencies.

*TEST_PLAN Table*

The TEST_PLAN table defines a series of tests that need to be conducted against each car.  Each test can be in more than one category.  The TEST_PLAN table shows what tests need to be conducted and in what category.  An acceleration test under the speed category, does not count for an acceleration test under performance.

```
The test plans look a bit like this:
Ford Focus 2006
    Speed
        acceleration
        topSpeed
        zeroToSixty
    Performance
        acceleration
        zeroToSixty
        breaking
        handling
    Safety
        breaking
        seating

Tesla Model S 2016
    Speed
        acceleration
        topSpeed
        zeroToSixty
        handling
    Performance
        acceleration
        handling
        smoothRide
    Comfort
        smoothRide
        seating
```

*TEST_INSTANCE Table*

The TEST_INSTANCE table tracks which tests (under which category) have been conducted and when.  A given test-category may have been conducted for a given car more than once.  Tests that are under no test plan may also have been conducted.

```
The TEST_INSTANCE table (all JOINed up) looks like this:
ID  CAR                 TEST_NAME       TEST_CATEGORY   GRADE   TEST_DATE
1   Ford Focus 2006     acceleration    Speed           C       2015-03-14  
2   Ford Focus 2006     acceleration    Speed           C       2015-03-17  
3   Ford Focus 2006     acceleration    Performance     D       2015-03-15  
4   Ford Focus 2006     acceleration    Performance     C       2015-03-16  
5   Ford Focus 2006     acceleration    Performance     B       2015-03-17  
6   Ford Focus 2006     zeroToSixty     Speed           B       2015-03-14  
7   Ford Focus 2006     zeroToSixty     Speed           C       2015-03-16  
8   Ford Focus 2006     breaking        Performance     C       2015-03-13
9   Tesla Model S 2016  acceleration    Speed           B       2015-03-17  
10  Tesla Model S 2016  acceleration    Speed           B       2015-03-15  
11  Tesla Model S 2016  acceleration    Performance     A       2015-03-16  
12  Tesla Model S 2016  acceleration    Performance     A       2015-03-14  
13  Tesla Model S 2016  handling        Performance     B       2015-03-19  
14  Tesla Model S 2016  handling        Performance     B       2015-03-12  
15  Tesla Model S 2016  handling        Performance     A       2015-03-13  
16  Tesla Model S 2016  handling        Performance     B       2015-03-18
17  Tesla Model S 2016  zeroToSisty     Speed           A       2015-03-14  --note that this test is not part of the test plan
```

**What I'm Trying to do**

I need to do several things involving aggregation.  I'm trying to get a list of all tests in a given test plan (for a single car) and JOIN the folloing from test instance:

1. The date the given test was first run in a given category.
2. The most recent date a given test was run in a category.
3. The total number of times a test was run in a given category.
4. Worst result for a given test-category
5. Most recent result for a given test-category.

I'm using the following query, and I've figured out how to get 1-4.  I'm still having trouble on 5:

```
SELECT
    tp.id,
    c.car_name
    tc.category_name,
    t.test_name,
    MIN(ti.test_date) as firstRun,       -- this grabs the date of the first time the test-category ran
    MAX(ti.test_date) as latest,         -- this grabs the latest date the test-category ran
    MIN(ti.grade) as worst,              -- this grabs the worst result fron the test-category
    COUNT(ti.test_date) as testRuns,     -- this grabs the total number of tests run from the category.
    ti.grade as latestGrade              -- this seems to give me the most recent grade from a test-category, but I can't be sure.
FROM
    testPlan tp
    LEFT JOIN car c ON c.id = tp.car_id
    LEFT JOIN test_category tc ON tc.id = tp.category_id
    LEFT JOIN test t ON t.id = tp.test_id
    LEFT JOIN test_instance ti ON (
        ti.car_id = tp.car_id
        AND ti.category_id = tp.category_id
        AND ti.test_id = tp.test_id
    )
WHERE
    tp.car_id = 5
GROUP BY
    tp.id;
```

For item number 5, `ti.grade as latestGrade` seems to give me the most recent grade for a given test-category, but I have no way of being assured of that.  I think I need some sort of `ORDER BY` to be certain.

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

```
The final query should return something like this:
ID  CAR             TEST_CATEGORY       TEST_NAME       FIRST_RUN   LATEST      TESTS_RUN   LATEST_GRADE    WORST_GRADE
11  Tesla Model S   Speed               acceleration    2015-03-15  2015-03-17  2           B               B
12  Tesla Model S   Speed               topSpeed        NULL        NULL        0           NULL            NULL
13  Tesla Model S   Speed               zeroToSixty     NULL        NULL        0           NULL            NULL
14  Tesla Model S   Speed               handling        NULL        NULL        0           NULL            NULL
15  Tesla Model S   Performance         acceleration    2015-03-14  2015-03-16  2           A               A
16  Tesla Model S   Performance         handling        2015-03-12  2015-03-19  4           A               B
17  Tesla Model S   Performance         smoothRide      NULL        NULL        0           NULL            NULL
18  Tesla Model S   Comfort             smoothRide      NULL        NULL        0           NULL            NULL
19  Tesla Model S   Comfort             seating         NULL        NULL        0           NULL            NULL

Resultset Note:
- there should be only one row per each test-category in the test plan (per car).  (9 items in Tesla S test plan).
```

**QUESTION**

1. What do I need to add to the query to ensure that latestGrade will always be the most recent?
2. Will `UNION ALL` cause a performance hit when joining non-plan results?  (my real dataset is 10k+ records returned).  Is there a way to refactor my query so that it would not need the `UNION ALL`?

Comment: SELECT GRADE  ,Max(TEST_DATE) from my_table group by grade

Comment: @Strawberry...  not 100% sure I understand.  Are you suggesting simply adding a `GROUP BY grade` to my `GROUP BY`?  My resultset should have one row per test-plan entry.  Adding the group by causes it to have more.

Comment: 1-4 can be done using simple `MIN()` and `MAX()` grouped by category. 5 requires joining with a query like the ones in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this "simple" query to get 1-4 and the highest ID for latest grade:

```
SELECT ti.car_id, ti.category_id, ti.test_id,
    MIN(ti.test_date) as firstRun,
    MAX(ti.test_date) as latest,
    MIN(ti.grade) as worst,
    COUNT(ti.test_date) as testRuns,
    MAX(ti.ID) as max_id -- use later to get latest grade
FROM test_instance ti
GROUP BY ti.car_id, ti.category_id, ti.test_id
```

Result for your test data:

```
| CAR_ID | CATEGORY_ID | TEST_ID |   firstRun |     latest | worst | testRuns | max_id |
|--------|-------------|---------|------------|------------|-------|----------|--------|
|      1 |           1 |       1 | 2015-03-14 | 2015-03-17 |     C |        2 |      2 |
|      1 |           1 |       3 | 2015-03-14 | 2015-03-16 |     B |        2 |      7 |
|      1 |           2 |       1 | 2015-03-15 | 2015-03-17 |     B |        3 |      5 |
|      1 |           2 |       8 | 2015-03-13 | 2015-03-13 |     C |        1 |      8 |
|      5 |           1 |       1 | 2015-03-15 | 2015-03-17 |     B |        2 |     10 |
|      5 |           2 |       1 | 2015-03-12 | 2015-03-19 |     A |        2 |     12 |
|      5 |           2 |       7 | 2015-03-14 | 2015-03-18 |     A |        4 |     16 |
|      5 |           5 |       9 | 2015-03-14 | 2015-03-14 |     A |        1 |     17 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6df83/4

And join the result with other tables:

```
SELECT sub.firstRun, sub.latest, sub.worst, sub.testRuns,
    ti.grade as latestGrade,
    c.car_name,
    tc.category_name,
    t.test_name,
    tp.id as test_plan_id
FROM (
    SELECT ti.car_id, ti.category_id, ti.test_id,
        MIN(ti.test_date) as firstRun,
        MAX(ti.test_date) as latest,
        MIN(ti.grade) as worst,
        COUNT(ti.test_date) as testRuns,
        MAX(ti.ID) as max_id -- use later to get latest grade
    FROM test_instance ti
    GROUP BY ti.car_id, ti.category_id, ti.test_id
) sub
JOIN test_instance ti ON ti.id = sub.max_id
JOIN car c            ON c.id  = sub.car_id
JOIN test_category tc ON tc.id = sub.category_id
JOIN test t           ON t.id  = sub.test_id
LEFT JOIN test_plan tp
    ON  tp.car_id      = sub.car_id
    AND tp.category_id = sub.category_id
    AND tp.test_id     = sub.test_id
```

Result:

```
|   firstRun |     latest | worst | testRuns | latestGrade |           CAR_NAME | CATEGORY_NAME |    TEST_NAME | test_plan_id |
|------------|------------|-------|----------|-------------|--------------------|---------------|--------------|--------------|
| 2015-03-14 | 2015-03-17 |     C |        2 |           C |    Ford Focus 2006 |         Speed | acceleration |            1 |
| 2015-03-14 | 2015-03-16 |     B |        2 |           C |    Ford Focus 2006 |         Speed |  zeroToSixty |            3 |
| 2015-03-15 | 2015-03-17 |     B |        3 |           B |    Ford Focus 2006 |   Performance | acceleration |            4 |
| 2015-03-13 | 2015-03-13 |     C |        1 |           C |    Ford Focus 2006 |   Performance |     breaking |            6 |
| 2015-03-15 | 2015-03-17 |     B |        2 |           B | Tesla Model S 2016 |         Speed | acceleration |           11 |
| 2015-03-12 | 2015-03-19 |     A |        2 |           A | Tesla Model S 2016 |   Performance | acceleration |           15 |
| 2015-03-14 | 2015-03-18 |     A |        4 |           B | Tesla Model S 2016 |   Performance |     handling |           16 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6df83/5

If the test is not "part of" test plan, `test_plan_id` will be NULL.

You might not even need the `test_plan_id` so you could remove the that column and the last JOIN.

Comment: +1 for the cool sub-query.  That was helpful.  The main query is returning too many results.  I'm trying to return exactly one row per item in the test_plan table.  I've edited the question to add the resultset I'm trying to get to.

Comment: I also refined the question to focus only on getting data if its from a test on the test plan.  I'll ask another question about the UNION_ALL if I need to.

Comment: You have multiple tests per cathegory. Which `test_name` do you want to select, if you want one row per category?